# Python Problem while generating contour plot

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a vector whose elements are : `a_i(m,n)= \sum_j y_i*y_j*m*n` . I want to generate a contour plot for each element `a_i` by varying `m` and `n`. To do this I have written the following code:

```
y=np.array([0.09,0.09,0.09])
def a(m,n):
    b=np.zeros((3))
    for i in range(len(y)):
        for j in range(len(y)):
            b[j]=b[j]+ ((y[i]*y[j])*m*n)
    return (b)
m=np.linspace(0,10,1000)
n=np.linspace(0,10,1000)
mv,nv= np.meshgrid(m,n)
```

Now when I try to evaluate `a(mv,nv)`, I get the following error:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_13298/262674515.py in <module>
----> 1 a(mv,nv)

/tmp/ipykernel_13298/891793447.py in a(m, n)
      4     for i in range(len(y)):
      5         for j in range(len(y)):
----> 6             b[j]=b[j]+ ((y[i]*y[j])*m*n)
      7     return (b)
      8 m=np.linspace(0,10,1000)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I can't reproduce this error message with numpy 1.21.5.

Comment: Sorry. The error message was different. I have updated the error section.

Comment: `m` and `n` are 2D arrays. `b[i]` is a single scalar element of the array `b`. You can't assign an array to a scalar. You should probably use some form of [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to achieve what you want.